# SQL select rows on zipcode range

Tags: mysql

I have four tables in my database:

**customers**
Customers contain a field called `zipcode`, for example: 1234AB

**users**
Users contain field `user_id`

**regions**
Regions are a range of zipcodes, for example: 1000 to 2000. Fields are called `zipcode_from` and `zipcode to`

**users_regions**
This table connects the users to regions, fields: `id`, `user_id`, `region_id`.

Users can be connected to multiple regions in the `users_regions` table.

I am trying to select all the customers that are available in the regions that the user is connected to. The issue I'm having is that the user can be connected to multiple regions, otherwise I could easily do something like this:

```
SELECT c.*
     , ur.* 
  FROM customers c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users a 
    ON a.id = c.advisor_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users_regions ur  
    ON c.region_id = ur.region_id 
 WHERE ur.user_id = 1 
HAVING ur.zipcode_from > c.zipcode 
   AND ur.zipcode_to < c.zipcode
```

(untested and probably is wrong)

How can I achieve this using a single query?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
SELECT *
  FROM customers c , users a, users_regions ur 
  Where a.id = c.advisor_id  
  AND c.region_id = ur.region_id 
  AND ur.user_id = 1 
HAVING ur.zipcode_from > c.zipcode 
   AND ur.zipcode_to < c.zipcode
```